# executable files in linux using (perm)?

Tags: shell, find

i'm trying to write out a list of the names of everything under the /etc directory that are executable to all other users and whose name starts or ends with a number.

```
find /etc "(" -name "[0-9]*" -o -name "*[0-9]" ")" -perm -o=x -print
```

But every time I get a wrong answer, can you help?

Comment: What wrong answers are you getting?

Comment: find: ‘/etc/ssl/private’: Permission denied

Comment: Your user doesn't have access to `/etc/ssl/private`. You can use `sudo` to run the command as root.

Comment: Note that you will also get directories as a response, since the x-bit means "permission to cd into". To exclude those from your answer, add a condition `-type f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the `zsh` shell, you can get that list of files with its advanced [filename generation globbing](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation); no external programs needed. In particular, using a *recursive glob*, alternation, and a *glob qualifier* that matches world-executable files:

```sh
zsh$ printf "%s\n" /etc/**/([0-9]*|*[0-9])(X)
/etc/alternatives/animate-im6
/etc/alternatives/c89
/etc/alternatives/c99
/etc/alternatives/compare-im6
/etc/alternatives/composite-im6
...
/etc/X11
/etc/X11/fonts/Type1
/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4
/etc/xdg/xfce4
/etc/xfce4
```

Do a `setopt glob_dots` first to match filenames starting with . like find does. Otherwise they get skipped.

---

If you're using `find`, you need the `-mode` argument to `-perm` to select files with at least the given permission bits (Which is actually what you have in your question and works for me)

```sh
find /etc \( -name "[0-9]*" -o -name "*[0-9]" \) -perm -o=x
```